# $\left(x+y\right)^{n}\neq x^{n}+\left(x+y\right)^{n}$ an inequality?

Tags: inequality

Is this expression $$\left(x+y\right)^{n}\neq x^{n}+\left(x+y\right)^{n}$$
 an inequality if $x$, $y$  and $n$ are (nonzero) positive integers?

The expression would seem to follow from basic axioms, for example: $c\neq a+c$. If $a=0$
  of course it is not an inequality; similarly with $x=0$
  in the first expression. Given that we state "positive integers"  (and redundantly "non-zero") is it not true that the "conditional" inequality holds for all positive integers?

Why do I ask this question?

When presented, as above, as part of a logical argument, the inequality was cited as "not always true, for example when $x=0$". This is equivalent to saying for $a,c>0$, $c\neq a+c$ is "not always true".

What am I missing?

As all positive integers having an integer nth root can be expressed as $\left(x+y\right)^{n}$
  ; can we generalize this inequality ?

Comment: It might depend on how the conditions are presented in the original text, but if they specifically exclude zero then you are correct and they are wrong.

Comment: Perhaps whoever said "when $x=0$" forgot the part where it was written that $x$ is a positive integer. There are ways to avoid this, for example write "since $x$ is positive" immediately after the inequality, but that's just a reminder for the (human) reader of the argument. If this was an exam question it might be a bit too harsh to deduct points from an answer that did not do this and was otherwise correct.

Comment: Yes it is an inequality.  Now, another question would be whether that inequality is true or not.

Comment: @GEdgar Would you please expand on your comment? If it were not "true" , would it not then be an inequality?

Comment: $A \le B$ is an inequality.  Regardless of what $A,B$ are.  For some values of $A,B$ it is true.  For other values of $A,B$ it is false.  But it is still an inequality.